# I have an Excel file with a worksheet that is completely white and on interactive. It's also not protected. How do I acces it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am working on a rather complex Excel file that has various Database connections and VBA code behind it. This file is getting pretty old and has had many people work on it during its life.

There is one worksheet that much of the VBA code passes data into and out of. When I look at the sheet, it is completely white. I see the column titles at the top but no row names. It also doesn't seem to be protected or locked via the normal mechanisms.

I need to troubleshoot some data that I believe is within the sheet.

Does anyone know how this sheet might be hidden like it is and how I can view the data inside it?

What I've tried:

1. I tried writing VBA code to select and copy 9999 rows from the blanked out sheet into a new sheet. The result is that I cannot scroll above row 10000 or view anything above row 1000, its as if row 10000 is the new row 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the [View] Ribbon; I suspect you have GridLines and row headings off, and panes frozen, too.

Comment: Grid lines and headings is checked, ruler is greyed out, and the freeze pane button seems to indicate that nothing is currently frozen

Comment: Can you strip the document from all important data and scripts and post it somewhere? Chances are, you will discover the part which causes your troubles while stripping. Otherwise, others will be able to take a close look at it.

Comment: Sadly that wouldn't be possible. Besides, I'm pretty sure there is data within the whited out sheet that I can't get rid of or view.

Answer (score 0):

And somehow I figured it out,

Apparently the people before me set the row height to 0. I figured out I could put my mouse at the top and drag down 1 row then change the row height.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone!